# Can I use every functionality of Vue in laravel by just using vue CDN? Basically I want to avoid NPM and node?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

Can I use every functionality of Vue in laravel by just using vue CDN?
Basically I want to avoid NPM and node?

Because I tried using NPM but got issues.

Comment: Sure you can. You can create app with Laravel only and use the Vue as more powerful alternative of jQuery.

Comment: You can use most of Vue without any tooling whatsoever, but one of the big disadvantages of not using any tooling is that you can't use [Single File Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). You can also read about some more stuff in the Tooling section of the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you , now I am satisfied to go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup no problem. Either CDN, or just put the file on your site somewhere. (which we do, to avoid issues with app cache).

As mentionned in the comments, you need tooling for single file components, but a workaround is to define your components in .js files, one per component, with js template literals (backticks) for the template element. That way, you have your behaviour and markup together, and only the css is unscoped.